# White bars issue top & bottom

Tags: html, css

The issue: [http://imgur.com/a/MQ70g](https://imgur.com/a/MQ70g)
I keep having this issue about margin bottom & top and keeps being white somehow i'm relative new to html & CSS so would expect some help. Friendly Greetings Wuttani :)

```
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<link rel='prefetch' href='https://short.elmnts.co/html/4cmaatl'>
<script src="../ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.9/jquery.marquee.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="gaf210imvustylez_youtubebox" style="width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden"><iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0IYght7FGdg?autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=0IYght7FGdg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<style>body { font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif; }</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:regular,bold&amp;subset=Latin">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<h1><title>$ marxSQUAD $</title></h1>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favoicon.ico" type="image/png"> 
</head>
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -99; width: 1920px; height: 1080px; margin: 0; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; padding: 0;">
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" 
    src="//www.youtube.com/embed/LuD3_umIxgw?autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;loop=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;disablekb=1&amp;enablejsapi=1">
  </iframe> 
</div>
<center><img src = "crt.gif" width="360" height="360">
<body background = "hvhgif" onload="doWave(0)"></body>
<pre>

                                                                                         $$\ 
                                                                                         $$ |
$$$$$$\$$$$\   $$$$$$\   $$$$$$\ $$\   $$\  $$$$$$$\  $$$$$$\  $$\   $$\  $$$$$$\   $$$$$$$ |
$$  _$$  _$$\  \____$$\ $$  __$$\\$$\ $$  |$$  _____|$$  __$$\ $$ |  $$ | \____$$\ $$  __$$ |
$$ / $$ / $$ | $$$$$$$ |$$ |  \__|\$$$$  / \$$$$$$\  $$ /  $$ |$$ |  $$ | $$$$$$$ |$$ /  $$ |
$$ | $$ | $$ |$$  __$$ |$$ |      $$  $$<   \____$$\ $$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$  __$$ |$$ |  $$ |
$$ | $$ | $$ |\$$$$$$$ |$$ |     $$  /\$$\ $$$$$$$  |\$$$$$$$ |\$$$$$$  |\$$$$$$$ |\$$$$$$$ |
\__| \__| \__| \_______|\__|     \__/  \__|\_______/  \____$$ | \______/  \_______| \_______|
                                                           $$ |                              
                                                           $$ |                              
                                      \__|         

</pre>
<h1>The Squad</h1>
<pre>[ <div id="marquee"></div> ]</pre>
<pre><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/marxSQUAD" target="_blank">Steam</a>
<pre><a href="report.html" target="_blank">Reportbot</a>
<pre><a href="https://discord.gg/whww9YA" target="_blank">Discord</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="aesthetic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="comet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="client.js"></script>
<div ID="theDiv" align="center"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center><h2>@~mArxSQUAD</h2>
</font>
</html> 
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

<-!-- main.css -->

```
#videobcg
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    z-index:-1000;
    overflow:hidden
}

body 
{
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #cccfd6;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(5,20,250,100), -1px -1px 0px rgba(5,20,250,100);
}

pre 
{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: monospace;
}

#center 
{               
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

a
 {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover 
{
    color: #6e0294
}

#marquee {
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be anything between your </head> and <body> tags.

Comment: Think i did correctly as you said, though didn't solve my issue that was the white bars

Comment: Or i've might done it wrong if that's the reason it's not working :P

Comment: also <div class="gaf210imvustylez_youtubebox"..... should also be in your <body> not in <head>

Comment: It's hard to tell without being able to see the actual page but maybe add margin: 0; to body{}

Comment: I personally do *{margin:0;} when I'm designing pages. I prefer to define my margins manually rather than use defaults which might change from browser to browser.

Comment: @fie do you own anydesk perhaps?

Comment: Somehow it solved itself by now and they're all gone thanks a lot for your help, fie <3